# Does good food is not cheap imply cheap food is not good?

Tags: logic

My prof said these two statements are logically equivilant, but it might be a mistake. Are they logically equivilent? It doesnt sound like it to me. How can all cheap food not be good just because good food is not cheap?

Comment: Use yahoo answer for these kind of questions.

Comment: @zee I wanted a CS perspective on it. This is for a bio couese so maybe it is right in a biology sense, so I asked it here.

Comment: Here is the kind of topics that can be asked, strictly coding related challenges with a piece of code to present. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic   . For your questions,you can read a scholarly article or other .edu sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is the contrapositive of a conditional statement.

> The contrapositive of a conditional statement of the form "If p then q" is  "If  ~q then  ~p".  Symbolically, the contrapositive of "p then q" is "~q then ~p". A conditional statement is logically equivalent to its contrapositive.

So in your example  the conditional statement is *good -> ~cheap* and thus the contrapositive statement is *cheap -> ~good*. So they both are equal.

If all good food is not cheap then, yes ofcourse the cheap food is not good because if the food is good and cheap, it contradicts with the former statement.